# Running hyperledger fabric java gateway example code throws The gateway identity must be set

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I am trying to write a fabric gateway app on basic-network, my code looks like this.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       // Load a file system based wallet for managing identities.
       Path walletPath = Paths.get("wallet");
       Wallet wallet = Wallet.createFileSystemWallet(walletPath);

       // load a CCP
       Path networkConfigPath = Paths.get("..", "..", "basic-network", "connection.yaml");

       Gateway.Builder builder = Gateway.createBuilder();
       builder.identity(wallet, "user1");
       builder.networkConfig(networkConfigPath).discovery(true);

       // create a gateway connection
       try (Gateway gateway = builder.connect()) {
          System.out.println("Hello");
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
```

when i run the code, it throws the error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The gateway identity must be set`

Please to help me to find how to set identity of this network?

my connection.yaml is

```
name: basic-network
version: 1.0.0
client:
    organization: Org1
    connection:
        timeout:
            peer:
                endorser: '300'
            orderer: '300'
channels:
    mychannel:
        orderers:
        - orderer.example.com
        peers:
            peer0.org1.example.com: {}
organizations:
    Org1:
        mspid: Org1MSP
        peers:
        - peer0.org1.example.com
        certificateAuthorities:
        - ca.example.com
orderers:
    orderer.example.com:
        url: grpc://localhost:7050
peers:
    peer0.org1.example.com:
        url: grpc://localhost:7051
certificateAuthorities:
    ca.example.com:
        url: http://localhost:7054
        caName: ca.example.com
```

there is a folder called `User1@org1.example.com` located in `basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/`

Comment: Can you use debug mode and understand what function launch this exception? Can you also post your connection.yaml? Did you generate user1 certificates first?

Comment: @RicNtt the `builder.connect()` function throws the error and i added the details in question description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I understood your problem. You are uncorrectly running the fabcar example from fabric samples.

Inside the Java folder you have 2 directories: **wallet** and **src**.
Inside src you will find your code, while in wallet you will store your user certificates.

Before running the application, you should create certificates and you don't have certificates at the moment.
Inside the folder where you run **ClientApp.java**, you should find 2 other files: **EnrollAdmin.java** and **RegisterUser.java**.

First of all, run EnrollAdmin.java. This will contact your CA and obtain certificates for an admin user.
Next, run RegisterUser.java to create user certificates.

Your ClientApp is currently looking for **user1** certificates, but you have no user1 in your wallet folder.
After doing so, run again ClientApp.java and you should be fine.
In your comment you mentioned about the `User1@org1.example.com` folder inside `basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/` but you should not use it for this example since you need X509 certificates released from your SDK contacting the CA.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still have questions about the last part of your answer about the X509 certificates, do you mean that this example does not support X509 certificates? and i have to run this app in a non-X509 certificated network?